# How to publish a ASP.NET MVC project with separated DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have these 5 projects: DataClass, DataLayer, ServiceLayer, ViewModel, ViewLayer. My ViewLayer project is a ASP.NET MVC project and it's the project that is going to be published.

My problem is Visual Studio used to detect my DbContext in datalayer and ask me for a connectionstring but recently it doesn't recognize it anymore and I'm having problem with it (I've tried to put connectionstring in my `web.config` file in the server but that didn't work.)

So the problem is the published project doesn't work since it doesn't have any connectionstring. **How can I publish my project with specifying it's connectionstring?**

P.S.

I've tried putting my connectionstring in ViewLayer->Properties->Package/Publish SQL but that doesn't work either.

P.S. 2

I've tried VS2013 Community and VS2015 Ultimate Preview (the earliest version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set proper config transformation and update

See below links
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

The following link has options for setting the connection string outside the web config

http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,604eadfe-46bf-4989-bac8-814e2701e52a.aspx

Comment: I did that. But I can't see the connectionstring in web.config in my server. Does Visual Studio encode it or hide it somewhere?

Comment: means you are doing something wrong. can you post your web.config transformation logic for checking. I have tried this and it used to work fine.

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks ;)